# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vek1'

Tags: python, attributeerror, numpy-ndarray

Every time I run this program I get the error:
**AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vek1'**

But why and how can I solve this problem? Thanks for the help.

The first one (main.py):

```
import os
os.getcwd()
import loaddata as ld
import symmetryvalues as sv
import centerofforce as cof
import numpy as np
import plotvalues as pv

"""
Load Data
"""
dataList = ld.loadData()

index = 1
data =dataList[index]

forceLeft = data.iloc[:,62:72].astype('float64').dropna()
forceRight = data.iloc[:,86:96].astype('float64').dropna()

vek1 = np.asarray([data.iloc[:, i].mean() for i in range(0, 5)])
vek2 = np.asarray([data.iloc[:, i].mean() for i in range(5, 10)])

xCoF, yCoF = cof.calcCoF(forceDataLeft = forceLeft, forceDataRight = forceRight)
pv.plotCoFAnimationpl(xCoF, yCoF, marker='*')

#%%
df = dataList[13].to_numpy()
print(df)
result = sv.symmetryRatio(df.vek1, df.vek2)
```

The second one (symmetryvalues.py):

```
def rowPass(data):
    for row in data:
        print(symmetryRatio(row))
        #print(self.symmetryIndex(row))
        #print("Important",self.symmetryRatio(data))
    return True

def symmetryRatio(L, R):
    result = L/R
    return result

def symmetryIndex(L, R):
    res = ((L-R)/(0.5*(L+R)))*100
    return res

def gaitAsymmetry(L, R):
    r = 0
    return r

def symmetryAngle(L, R):
    solution = 0
    return solution
```

**EDIT:**

This is my example csv - Data with five row's (but I also can have a data with 100 or more row's):

1.00,0.80,0.40,0.20,0.50,1.20,0.90,0.30,0.20,0.34

1.10,0.85,0.50,0.21,0.59,1.30,0.95,0.40,0.21,0.42

0.90,0.90,0.45,0.23,0.50,1.10,1.00,0.35,0.23,0.35

1.05,0.70,0.40,0.28,0.57,1.25,0.80,0.30,0.28,0.38

0.95,0.75,0.45,0.30,0.60,1.15,0.85,0.35,0.30,0.42

vek1 should stand for the first five values of each row and vek2 for the last 5 values of each row. 
The Plan is:
I want to calculate (in main.py) the mean value of each column (that is that, what I have tried). Then I have ten values. The first five values are written in one vector (vek1) and the last five values are written also in one vector (vek2). Then I want to use the method symmetryRatio(L, R) from symmetryvalues.py to divide vec1 by vec2.

I hope it's clearer now.

**EDIT**

With:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'vek1': vek1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'vek2': vek2})
result = sv.symmetryRatio(df1.vek1, df2.vek2)
```

I get the output:

```
The result is: 0    0.833333
1    0.888889
2    1.294118
3    1.000000
4    1.445026
```

How can I form 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 into specific names?

Comment: Because it doesn't. You haven't named your df columns and there is no method `vek1`. I'm unclear on why you expected this to work. A variable name is not some meta information that will be carried over when you create a data frame; you need to name the columns explicitly in some way

Comment: I have completed my question. Please look at my Edit. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear from my first comment. _There is no vek1 name_. You literally didn't specify it as a name in the creation of the dataframe e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'vek1': vek1})`

Comment: Your first comment wasn't unclear. But what you wrote wasn't that what I want to do. So I have to do it in an other way. Maybe you can read my edit in my question. Could you please help me, if you understand what I really want to do?

Comment: I am trying to help you. `result = sv.symmetryRatio(df.vek1, df.vek2)` cannot work because you're trying to access attributes on a df that you appear to think just magically exist. You need to construct the df such that it has columns named `vek1` and `vek2`, exactly as I tried to illustrate in my last comment

Comment: Do I even need this? Because I just want to have 5 values in my output, when I run this program. 
Vec1 should just represent the mean values of the first five columns and vec2 should just represent the mean values of the last five columns. And than I want to divide vec1 by vec2 with symmetryRatio()

Comment: That's the part where "I'm unclear on why you expected this to work". The `.` is to  access attributes, but you never set the attributes. They can't come from global names. Perhaps I can help better if you explained why you think `df.vek1` would work

Comment: I don't now. I thought that it maybe worked. But apparently I can't do it that way because it doesn't work. So I have to that, what I want to do in an other way, but I don't know how.

Comment: Just try `df = pd.DataFrame({'vek1': vek1})` as I suggested. Then `df.vek1` exists, and you can pass multiple columns like that to the dataframe constructor. You can put `vek1 = np.asarray([data.iloc[:, i].mean() for i in range(0, 5)])` into a df just fine, but it won't be possible to reference it as `vek1` any more; it'll just get the default column name of `0`. The python variable name is not carried over. You need to explicitly name it

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @ragonjosh Thank you for your help. I added something in my question above. Maybe you can look at it and explain me how I can do this, please.